# Number in front of Facebook share button

Tags: facebook, button, share

I have a blog at http://pawan269.wordpress.com where I post my photos.

It has a share utility which I have enable from administrative interface. In this sharing utility there is an option to share using Facebook.

Not sure why it shows a number in front of "Facebook" text inside button, attached is a screen grab of a post Facebook share button.

[image: Facebook share button with number]

Please let me know if anyone knows the right answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any number in front of "Facebook".

Comment: Hi Jan, please refer attached image in the post it reads 18... at my blog there are posts with different numbers... some times missing... not sure why

Comment: The number is not in-front of Facebook, but behind it. At least if you read from left to right. So I really don't know what yo're on about :)

Comment: Hi Jan, seem my perception of front and back is not right...

Comment: By any chance you know the answer of question?

Comment: Check FB's documentation for the share button. By default it displays number of shares for that content. But you can hide it if you want.

Comment: I think the plugin that is being used is ShareDaddy: 

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sharedaddy/screenshots/

The number is the share count and there may be an option within the plugin to turn this off.

Comment: Thanks Neil... I don't want to turn it off... if its count of shares on Facebook then its good to have... I share once every time I post a blog... not sure who else is sharing this ... there will be some fans of my photographs :) ... by any chance "Can we figure out who has shared post other than me?"